# Read Google Trend Table

Tags: jquery, trend

I want to read data table response from google trend.

Here is the url : http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=stromae&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3

I've tried getJSON request but the data don't seem to be JSON or JSONP so how can I read it using jquery ?

Comment: This appears to require some sort of google api to use. I suggest reading the google documentation related to this api. Requesting it with jquery ajax methods is going to be overly-complicated if even possible.

Comment: As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/9kmSr/ jquery doesn't handle callbacks that are objects very well.

Comment: It's definitely possible though: http://jsfiddle.net/9kmSr/1/ Note however it doesn't call the success callback of the ajax request.